# Socket.io not working in the net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket, socket.io

I created a simple chatroom using socket.io. I have these scripts in my index.html :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://imageworkz.asia:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });
```

when i change the connection to http://localhost:8080 and start it using 'node app.js' command in console, it works fine but when I upload it and change it to http://imageworkz.asia:8080, it is not working whenever I go to url: http://imageworkz.asia:8080. Am I missing something or are there still things I should do to make it work when it is uploaded? or am I going to the wrong url? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your node.js version to the latest one on the net (http://imageworkz.asia:8080).

Also check whether all necessary node modules are installed on the net, and if needed, change the logic such that you dont require prompt() to transmit a message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think this should work:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://imageworkz.asia');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append(''+username + ': ' + data + '
');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('' + key + '');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });
```

it just removes :8080

Comment: Consider editing your answer to explain why the code in your answer "should work".